# Export to excel file shows error

Tags: php, format, export-to-excel

I am trying to use a plugin that converts the posts of a blog to to .xls format. When i try to open the .xls file i get an error that file format is different or file is corrupt. This is the code for creating .xls file.

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['Submit']) && isset($_POST['post_type']) &&  isset($_POST['ext']) ) {
    $post_type = $_POST['post_type'];
    $ext = $_POST['ext'];
    $str = '';
    if ( is_multisite() ) {
      $blog_info = get_blog_list(0, 'all');
      foreach ($blog_info as $blog) {
        switch_to_blog($blog['blog_id']);
        include('loop.php');
        restore_current_blog();
      }
    } else {
      include('loop.php');
    }
    $filename = strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',get_bloginfo('name'))) .'-urls.' . $ext;
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel;");
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, charset=utf-8;");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename);

    print $str;//$str variable is used in loop.php
    wp_redirect(admin_url('admin.php?page=../export-2-excel.php&noheader=true'));
    exit();
  }
?>
```

the code for loop.php is

```
<?php
  if($post_type != 'comment_authors') {
    query_posts(array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'order'=>'DESC', 'post_type' => $post_type));//-1 is for all posts
    $str .= '<table>
              <tr>
                <td colspan=7>' . get_bloginfo('name').'
              </tr>';
    if (have_posts()) {
      $str .= '<tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Url</th>
                <th>Created on</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Categories</th>
                <th>Tags</th>
              </tr>';
      while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();

        $all_cats = '';
        foreach( (get_the_category()) as $category) {
          $all_cats .= $category->cat_name . ', ';
        }
        $all_cats = substr($all_cats, 0, -2);


        $all_tags = '';
        $posttags = get_the_tags();
        if ($posttags) {
          foreach( (get_the_tags()) as $tag) {
            $all_tags .= $tag->name . ', ';
          }
          $all_tags = substr($all_tags, 0, -2);
        }
        global $post;

        $str.= '
          <tr>
            <td>' . mb_convert_encoding(get_the_title(), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8') . '</td>
            <td>' . mb_convert_encoding($post->post_content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8') . '</td>
            <td>' . get_permalink() .'</td>
            <td>' . get_the_date('Y-m-d', '', '', FALSE) .'</td>
            <td>' . get_the_author() .'</td>
            <td>' . $all_cats . '</td>
            <td>' . $all_tags . '</td>
          </tr>';
      }
      wp_reset_query();
    } else {
      $str .= '<tr colspan="6"><td>No post found.</td></tr>';
    }
    $str.= '</table><br/></br>';
  } else {
    global $wpdb,$table_prefix;
    $str .= '<table>
            <tr>
              <td colspan=6>' . get_bloginfo('name').'
            </tr>';
    $str .= '<tr>
              <th>Commenter</th>
              <th>Email Address</th>
              <th>Url</th>
              <th>Created on</th>
              <th>IP Address</th>
              <th>Comments</th>
            </tr>';
   $commenters = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(comment_ID) AS count, comment_ID, comment_author, comment_author_email, comment_author_url, comment_date, comment_author_IP FROM $table_prefix"."comments WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND comment_type = '' GROUP BY comment_author, comment_author_email ORDER BY comment_author ASC, comment_date DESC;");

    foreach ($commenters as $row)
    {
      $str.= '<tr>
               <td>'.$row->comment_author.'</td>';
      $str.= '<td>'.$row->comment_author_email."</td>";
      $str.= '<td>'.$row->comment_author_url."</td>";
      $str.= '<td>'.$row->comment_date."</td>";
      $str.= '<td>'.$row->comment_author_IP."</td>";
      $str.= '<td>'.$row->count."</td>
             </tr>";
    }
  }
```

Is there something wrong while creating the .xls file?

Comment: Interesting code here would be `export-2-excel.php`, rather than the pieces you posted.

Comment: You should clear any response before sending your excel file to browser. use ob_flush() before create header.

Comment: @YograjGupta i will try that. Also how can make it not to send the file to browser but send it as an email attachment to any email id?

Comment: It's difficult to escape that message, because what you're saving as an .xls file is not an .xls file but html markup. MS Excel will successfully import it, but the latest versions will always give that message because you're telling it porkie pies pretending that an html file is an .xls file... and it knows you're lying. The only way to suppress that message is to be honest, and if you create an .xls file, create a real .xls file rather than html in disguise

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks and +1 for the comment :) . This should have been posted as an answer.